# VBA Loop every two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly straight forward line of code which loops through the rows on a dataset. However I have realised that I am repeating this code within the loop 10 times because I need to do the same thing every other column.

How can I loop through columns, so that this code works from Y to AA to AC columns etc rather than manually reapeating this for each column within the loop?

```
For i = 1 To Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & i + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to paste something in more than one column, try a nested loop, going through columns and rows:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long

    For lngRow = 1 To 10
        For lngCol = 25 To 29
            With ActiveSheet
                .Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = "here we paste"
            End With
        Next lngCol
    Next lngRow

End Sub
```

You would get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `Step 2` in your `For` loop.

```
For i = 1 To Count Step 2
    ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

---

If you want to loop through columns, you need something like the code below:

```
Dim Row As Long
Dim col As Long

For col = 25 To Count Step 2
     ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, col).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next col
```

Comment: That awkward moment when I realize why you have declared `Row` and `col` the way you have done it ... Been there, done that :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `Cells` rather than `Range` and add an outer loop with `Step 2`:

```
For j = 25 To 31 Step 2 ' Every other col from col Y to col ACC
    For i = 1 To Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Next i
Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can skip every second column between *Y* and *AR* like this:

```
Dim currCol As Integer, currRow As Integer
rowsToLoop = 4
For currCol = Columns("Y").Column To Columns("AR").Column Step 2
    For currRow = 1 To rowsToLoop 
        Debug.Print "Current Cell: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow + 1, currCol).Address
        ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow + 1, currCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next currRow
Next currCol
```

I gather you either manually or programmatically **copy** a cell or range before your code runs...  If you're doing it manually, note that there is a `Copy` range method.  For example to copy cell T5, you would use:

```
Range("T5").Copy
```

Also note that I change the name of your variable for "the number of rows to repeat" from `Count` to `myCount` since `Count` is a reserved word and shouldn't be used as a variable name.